# Adding custom name suffixes to Nameparser in Python

Tags: python

I'm using [Nameparser](https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customize.html#parser-customization-examples) to parse the names of a database of full names stored as a single string. I've been trying to add [custom](https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customize.html#parser-customization-examples) suffixes with little success.

```
from nameparser import HumanName
from nameparser.config import Constants

constants = Constants()
constants.suffix_acronyms.add(
    'A.O.'
)

HumanName("Brock N. Little, A.O.", constants=constants)
# <HumanName : [
#     title: ''
#     first: 'A.O.'
#     middle: ''
#     last: 'Brock N. Little'
#     suffix: ''
#     nickname: ''
# ]>
```

I would like the following output instead:

```
# <HumanName : [
#     title: ''
#     first: 'Brock'
#     middle: 'N.'
#     last: 'Little'
#     suffix: 'A.O.'
#     nickname: ''
# ]>
```

I have a lot of random suffixes that I would like to include that are not captured by default:

- B.Sc. (Geology)
- B.E. (Mining)
- Eng.
- C.A.
- O.C.
- S.O.M.
- P.C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look [at the defaults](https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules.html#nameparser.config.Constants), acronyms don't include the periods.

```
constants.suffix_acronyms.add('ao')
```

works for me.

For "B.Sc. (Geology)" and "B.E. (Mining)"... I don't think nameparser knows how to deal with that. I think you'd just have to add `bsc` and `be` and have a bit of code like this:

```
if name.suffix == 'B.Sc.' and name.nickname == 'Geology':
    name.suffix += f' ({name.nickname})'
    name.nickname = ''
```